# Install Java MP3 library

Tags: gpio, java

I am working on a sound board for the raspberry pi with Java.

I used the libary Pi4j to make it possible to read Gpio pins.

To play a Mp3 we modified the code of an Pi4j example

```
  button2.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
        @Override
        public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
            // display pin state on console
            System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
            System.out.println(" Button Goat!");
            play("goat.mp3");
        }

    });
```

our play method:

```
 public static void play(String path) {

    try {
        FileInputStream FIS = new FileInputStream(path);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(FIS);

        player = new Player(bis);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException | JavaLayerException ex) {

    }
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {

                player.play();

            } catch (JavaLayerException ex) {

            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

When i put the java file on my RaspberryPi, and i compile the file i get this output

Image:
http://gyazo.com/0dc5e6cbe84ad00eed7d4a9df2b6b782

what i understand from this errors, is that the Libary's are not found.
how can i make this work?

Comment: Include the library in the compiletime classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Include the classpath to the javazoom lib on your command line.